# How to map an existing question to corresponding bug report?

Tags: discussion

This question exactly describes a problem I'm having that makes my system unusable
https://askubuntu.com/questions/140028/12-04-occasionally-freezes-when-image-viewer-opens-pictures-possibly-graphics-d

The question was "closed" with a note that it was a bug and needed to be reported as such. I assume it was reported as a bug by the original questioner or someone else who experienced it. How can I locate the existing bug report related to this question and find out if there is a fix or workaround. As with many others on this board, I do not know how to categorize the bug, and I am intimadated by the amount of technical detail required to report a bug; I just want it fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally the person would leave a comment with a link to the bug report. If this doesn't happen you can search for the bug in http://bugs.launchpad.net or via Google.

If you still can't find it then you can report the bug, and then provide a link to the Ask Ubuntu question and provide as much of your own detail as you can.

If you follow the bug reporting instructions and the tool is able to grab crash/freeze information the Launchpad will eventually figure out it's a duplicate when it analyzes the data.

Comment: Yeah, this.  There's no "mapping" to say "This is [this bug]" and then redirect to the bug report or something.  LInking the report in comments is the easiest.